# Custom Hibernate insert for collections, counterpart of @WhereJoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to map a relationship with an extra attribute (flag) on a join table, but without explicitly defining this join table in an Entity.

Problem:

Business is assigned to 0 or 1 main country, business also is linked to 0 or more secondary countries.

I have three tables: `Business`, `Country`, `Business_Country`

In my `Business`, I have a `@WhereJoinTable` which works quite nice for retrieving:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinTable(
        name="business_country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="business_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="country_id")
)
@WhereJoinTable(clause="is_main = 1")
private Country mainCountry;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="business_country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="business_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="country_id")
)
@WhereJoinTable(clause="is_main = 0")
private Set<Country> secondaryCountries = new HashSet<>();
```

I wonder what the counterpart would be of this `@WhereJoinTable` to perform saves.

Just creating the entity `Business` and adding the countries to it gives a constraint violation:

```
cannot insert NULL into ("TESTSCHEMA"."BUSINESS_COUNTRY"."IS_MAIN")
```

What I'd like to do is that is_main is set to `1` for `mainCountry` and to `0` for all entries in  `secondaryCountries`.

I was wondering if there was something possible with a custom `@SQLInsert`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`@SQLInsert`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert.html) to specify a custom sql insert statement for the association table:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinTable(
        name="business_country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="business_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="country_id")
)
@WhereJoinTable(clause="is_main = 1")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into business_country (business_id, country_id, is_main) values (?, ?, 1)")
private Country mainCountry;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="business_country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="business_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="country_id")
)
@WhereJoinTable(clause="is_main = 0")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into business_country (business_id, country_id, is_main) values (?, ?, 0)")
private Set<Country> secondaryCountries = new HashSet<>();
```

[This](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/querysql-cud.html) and [this](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/using-sqlinsert-to-insert-entity-in-hibernate-with-custom-sql/) articles can also be helpful (pay attention to ordering of columns in the insert statements).

Comment: In ManyToMany relation the @SQLInsert will be getting values for the relations table (and not to the related entiry)